# Javascript help with DOM..does not get updated?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a bunch of links stylized like this:

```
<div id="friend_names_list">

<div class="dropdown_input"><span>1</span><span>Name1</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name2</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name3</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name4</span></div>


</div>
```

With the following function i want to select the next link after the selected one. Indicated by the 1 in the span:

```
 function select_friendinbox()
{
    var arr_names=document.getElementById("friend_names_list").getElementsByClassName("dropdown_input");
    var match=0;

    for(var a=0;a<arr_names.length;a++)
    {
        if(arr_names[a].childNodes[0].innerHTML=='1')
{
arr_names[a].childNodes[0].innerHTML='0';
match=a;
}

}


    arr_names[match+1].childNodes[0].innerHTML='1'; 

}
```

However if i call the function. It does change so that the second name is selected:

```
<div id="friend_names_list">

<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name1</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>1</span><span>Name2</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name3</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_input"><span>0</span><span>Name4</span></div>


</div>
```

But when I call the function again it says match is 0 and selects the second name and not the third. I don't know why this happens maybe its my coding logic or something ;) It appears as if javascript is not returning the updated dom..and thats why match stays at 0?? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Working for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/NTNDu/](http://jsfiddle.net/NTNDu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code here, and it worked (made a small change so that it loops as well because it threw an error)

http://jsfiddle.net/dBhBu/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to take the `var match = 0` outside the `select_friendinbox()` function. Otherwise every time you call the function it gets set back to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well I want to loop through the elements to get the new match and therefore i set it to 0 because the innerHTML is used to determine the match. So even though i put it to 0 when I find a match (arr_names[a].childNodes[0].innerHTML=='1') which should be the second div therefore (a=1) match=a=1;